XSLT: Display element and child element based on child value
My XML code displays all the address of an employee and its usage type. The address must be display only if it has specific usage type. The others must be removed.
Below is the xml.
<peci:Person_Communication>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME1</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME2</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME3</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-8</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-9</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME4</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-9</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME5</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME6</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Třebíč</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-10</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-8</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
        <peci:Usage>
            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
        </peci:Usage>
    </peci:Address>
</peci:Person_Communication>

Address's that only contains COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1 , COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16 and COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6 and Address that do not have Usage element must be displayed. rest has be removed.
Below is the logic I have written in the XSLT code.
<xsl:template match="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address">
    <xsl:variable name="AddUsage1" select="peci:Usage/peci:Usage_Behavior_ID[.='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="AddUsage2" select="peci:Usage/peci:Usage_Behavior_ID[.='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-9' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-8' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-10' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-11' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-12' or .='COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-13']"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$AddUsage1 and not($AddUsage2)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$AddUsage1 and $AddUsage2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="peci:Usage_Type|peci:Address_Line_1|peci:Address_Line_3|peci:Address_Line_4|peci:City|peci:Postal_Code|peci:Country|peci:Country_Region"/>
            <peci:Usage>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$AddUsage1"/>
            </peci:Usage>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not($AddUsage1) and not($AddUsage2)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>`

And below is the output.
<peci:Person_Communication>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME1</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
        <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
        <peci:City>Treb�/peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
            <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
            <peci:Usage>
                <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
            </peci:Usage>
        </peci:Address>
        <peci:Address>
            <peci:Usage_Type>HOME2</peci:Usage_Type>
            <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
            <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
            <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
            <peci:City>Treb�/peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
                <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
                <peci:Usage>
                    <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                </peci:Usage>
                <peci:Usage>
                    <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                </peci:Usage>
            </peci:Address>
            <peci:Usage_Type>HOME4</peci:Usage_Type>
            <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
            <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
            <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
            <peci:City>Treb�/peci:City>
                <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
                <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
                <peci:Usage xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">
                    <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                </peci:Usage>
                <peci:Address>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME5</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
                    <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
                    <peci:City>Treb�/peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
                        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
                    </peci:Address>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME6</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Gen. Sochora</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:Address_Line_3>31</peci:Address_Line_3>
                    <peci:Address_Line_4>957</peci:Address_Line_4>
                    <peci:City>Treb�/peci:City>
                <peci:Postal_Code>674 01</peci:Postal_Code>
                        <peci:Country>CZ</peci:Country>
                        <peci:Usage xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">
                            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                            <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                        </peci:Usage>
                    </peci:Person_Communication>

for the cases where both Variables $AddUsage1 and $AddUsage2 are present the element peci:Address/ is missing and all values for Usage behaviour are placed under a single peci:Usage instead of separate elements. Please help me fix the below logic.
<xsl:when test="$AddUsage1 and $AddUsage2">
    <xsl:copy-of select="peci:Usage_Type|peci:Address_Line_1|peci:Address_Line_3|peci:Address_Line_4|peci:City|peci:Postal_Code|peci:Country|peci:Country_Region"/>
    <peci:Usage>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$AddUsage1"/>
    </peci:Usage>
</xsl:when>


Please provide a clearer statement of the rule you want to implement, and also add the exact expected result.

You're more likely to get an answer if you make it easier for us. One way to do that is to cut out irrelevant detail. For example, replace long strings like COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6 by something shorter. Remember that it's far easier to see what's wrong with the code if it all appears on one screen without scrolling. Indeed, if you try to reduce the problem to its essentials in this way, you might well spot the solution yourself.

From what I understand you can just use an XPath expression that selects all the relevant Addresses to copy?

Firstly, let me remind you that the best way to get a prompt response is to take care when asking your question that you've provided all the relevant information.
You need to include:

the input data (yours is invalid because it omits a declaration for the peci namespace prefix; in my example I've bound peci to a placeholder value not-supplied)
your existing running code, in full (yours is not a complete stylesheet)

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Here's an answer to your question, if I've understood it correctly.
I understand you want to remove any peci:Address if it contains a peci:Usage/peci:Usage_Behavior_ID whose value is something other than one of these three acceptable values:

COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1
COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16
COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6

My example solution uses an "identity template" to copy the document, and defines another template to match unacceptable peci:Address elements, which overrides the identity template for those elements. The peci:Address-matching template is empty, so the result of matching is to ignore that element, which is therefore not copied to the output.
See the section about "identity transformation" in the XSLT 2.0 specification, which gives an example of copying a document and ignoring a particular note element. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e17568
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:peci="not-supplied">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="true"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!--
Match, and ignore, any Address which contains
   a Usage/Usage_Behaviour_ID for which
      it's not the case that the ID appears in the list of acceptable IDs
-->

  <xsl:template match="
    peci:Address[
      peci:Usage/peci:Usage_Behavior_ID[
        not ( . = 
          (
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6'
          )
        )
      ]
    ]
  "/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

By the way, in case you were wondering, the boolean expression
        not ( . = 
          (
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6'
          )
        )

is not equivalent to
        . != (
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-1',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-16',
            'COMMUNICATION_USAGE_BEHAVIOR_TENANTED-3-6'
          )

In the first expression, the = operator returns true if any of the items in the sequence are equal to the context item.
In the second expression, the != operator returns true if any of the items in the sequence are different to the context item.
In general not($A = $B) is not the same as $A != $B. See the XPath specification's section about "General Comparisons" for details.
